# Session variable fine in one action, null in next

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I have a simple application. When a user logs in it creates a session variable and redirects them to another controller that pull up some info from the database. I need to store this to a session variable then return it to the view. The initial part is fine, it returns it and I see the information. However, when I try to create a search query it returns that the session is null even though I never clear it.

```
public ActionResult ShowCourses()
{
    if (Session["Username"] != null)
    {
        string Username = Session["Username"].ToString();

        using (DefaultConnection db = new DefaultConnection())
        {
            var model = from c in db.Courses
                        where c.Username == Username
                        select c;

            Session["Courses"] = model.ToList();
            var Courses = Session["Courses"];
            return View(Courses);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Login", "Users");
    }
}
```

But when I try to run a search query to loop through the session, it brings back that `Courses` is null. The problem is that `coursesQuery` returns null and I'm not sure why.

```
public ActionResult SearchCourses(string query)
{
    if (Session["Username"] != null)
    {
        var coursesQuery = Session["Courses"] as IEnumerable<Course>;

        if (coursesQuery != null)
        {
            // Do Something
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did a `.ToList()` on the course colleciton before setting to Session.

Try this. Use `List<Course>` when you read it back.

```
if (Session["Courses"] != null)
{
  var coursesQuery = (List<Course>) Session["Courses"];
}
```

Comment: It seems to not be null anymore but now I can't perform a query such as `coursesQuery = coursesQuery.Where(c => c.CourseName.Contains(query));` Is there another way to accomplish this?

Comment: It is a `List`. you should be able to query it using LINQ as long as you have included System.Linq namspace to your class. Are you getting any errors ? Compile time / Run time ?

Comment: `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Student.Models.Course>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Student.Models.Course>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)`

Comment: The result of your `Where` is `IEnumerable<Course>`. You need to call `ToList()` again to convert ito a list.  `coursesQuery = coursesQuery.Where(c => c.CourseName.Contains(query)).ToList()`;